# How to Configure Docker server with the Jenkins server running on AWS?

Tags: docker, jenkins, configure

I got two servers, 1  Linux AMI with Jenkins and other  Linux AMI with Docker running on AWS.I want to configure my Jenkins server with my docker server. How I can achieve that? Basically I want both the instances to communicate and then I will be using my Jenkins instance to create a pipeline and build the docker images and push it to Dockerhub, for which I will be using my docker instance

Answer (score 0):

One instance suffice for Jenkins installations(you must install Java and Docker on it beforehand). Here is example of my Docker inside Docker configuration,where we run containers on the host(read more in fantastic Bibin Wilson blog, [docker-in-docker](https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/), to get clear picture of dind)

Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins

USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") $(lsb_release -cs) stable" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.26.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
    
RUN usermod -u $HOST_UID jenkins
RUN groupmod -g $HOST_GID docker
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    jenkins:
        build:
            context: ./
            args:
                HOST_UID: ${HOST_UID}
                HOST_GID: ${HOST_GID}
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
          - "JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx3g -Xms2G"
        volumes:
            - ${HOST_DOCKER}:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ${HOST_JENKINS_DATA}:/var/jenkins_home
        ports:
            - "${HOST_WWW}:8080"
            - "${HOST_OTHER}:50000"
```

.env variables file

```
HOST_WWW=8180
HOST_OTHER=8181
HOST_DOCKER=/var/run/docker.sock
HOST_JENKINS_DATA=/home/mikisamal/jenkins_home
HOST_UID=1001
HOST_GID=999
```